# Format Different Credit Card Types in Vue.js (15 or 16 digits)

Tags: regex, vue.js

Currently, the format of credit card is correct when there are 15 digits but it is not working for 16 digits. How can I handle the scenario where there is a credit card with 16 digits?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    card: ''
  },
  watch: {
    'card': function() {
      this.card = this.card.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="card" maxlength="19">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you thought about something like this https://vuejsexamples.com/input-mask-library-for-vue-js-based-on-credit-card-input-mask/ ?

It does NOT answer your question it is just a hint that could make the usability better.